# Nested fragments survive screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, android-nested-fragment

I've faced with an issue with Nested Fragments in Android. 
When I rotate the screen the Nested Fragments survive somehow. 
I've come up with a sample example to illustrate this issue.

```
public class ParentFragment extends BaseFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

         getChildFragmentManager()
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .add(getId(), new ParentFragmentChild(), ParentFragmentChild.class.getName())
                 .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        log.verbose("onResume(), numChildFragments: " + getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().size());
    }     
}

public class ParentFragmentChild extends BaseFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, null);
    }
}
```

BaseFragment just logs method calls. 
This is what I see when I rotate the screen.

### When Activity initially appears

```
ParentFragment﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragment{420d0a98 #0 id=0x7f060064}
ParentFragment﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragment﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragmentChild{420d08d0 #0 id=0x7f060064 com.kinoteatr.ua.filmgoer.test.ParentFragmentChild}
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragment﹕ onResume()
ParentFragment﹕ onResume(), numChildFragments: 1
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onResume()
```

### Screen rotation #1

```
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onPause()
ParentFragment﹕ onPause()
ParentFragment﹕ onSaveInstanceState()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onSaveInstanceState()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onStop()
ParentFragment﹕ onStop()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDestroyView()
ParentFragment﹕ onDestroyView()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDestroy()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDetach()
ParentFragment﹕ onDestroy()
ParentFragment﹕ onDetach()
ParentFragment﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragment{4211bc38 #0 id=0x7f060064}
ParentFragment﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragmentChild{420f4180 #0 id=0x7f060064 com.kinoteatr.ua.filmgoer.test.ParentFragmentChild}
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragment﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragmentChild{42132a08 #1 id=0x7f060064 com.kinoteatr.ua.filmgoer.test.ParentFragmentChild}
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragment﹕ onResume()
ParentFragment﹕ onResume(), numChildFragments: 2
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onResume()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onResume()
```

### Screen rotation #2

```
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onPause()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onPause()
ParentFragment﹕ onPause()
ParentFragment﹕ onSaveInstanceState()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onSaveInstanceState()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onSaveInstanceState()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onStop()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onStop()
ParentFragment﹕ onStop()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDestroyView()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDestroyView()
ParentFragment﹕ onDestroyView()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDestroy()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDetach()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDestroy()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onDetach()
ParentFragment﹕ onDestroy()
ParentFragment﹕ onDetach()
ParentFragment﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragment{42122a48 #0 id=0x7f060064}
ParentFragment﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragmentChild{420ffd48 #0 id=0x7f060064 com.kinoteatr.ua.filmgoer.test.ParentFragmentChild}
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragmentChild{420fffa0 #1 id=0x7f060064 com.kinoteatr.ua.filmgoer.test.ParentFragmentChild}
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragment﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onAttach(): ParentFragmentChild{42101488 #2 id=0x7f060064 com.kinoteatr.ua.filmgoer.test.ParentFragmentChild}
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onCreate()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onViewCreated()
ParentFragment﹕ onResume()
ParentFragment﹕ onResume(), numChildFragments: 3
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onResume()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onResume()
ParentFragmentChild﹕ onResume()
```

They keep getting multiplied. Does anybody know why is that ?

Comment: I have no idea but I faced the same situation with nested fragments once and had the occurence that setting myFragment.retainOnInstance(true) actually caused the fragment to 'die' and vice versa. Can't remember the exact scenario though.

Comment: did you put ParentFragment  into the backstack

Comment: I didn't do anything special

Comment: @Ascorbin Thank you very much bruuuh. 2.5 years later... I have a fragment x with `ViewPager`, and surely `ViewPager` has fragments as child too. On rotation, ViewPager's children lost its properties. I'm so confused why parent fragment x is okay but its children weren't. Been days debugging and reading SO for this problem, and setting `RetainInstance = true` on parent fragment x (the one hosting ViewPager) make it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **When I rotate the screen the Nested Fragments survive somehow.**

They survive for the same reason the `ParentFragment` survives even when you are not
retaining the instance with `setRetainInstance()`. The `FragmentManager` is that reason,
in this case the `ChildFragmentManager` the `ParentFragment` uses to handle the nested fragments.

Some things you need to know:

- The `FragmentManager` is responsible for managing the fragments and
  adding them to the activity's view hierarchy.
- The `FragmentManager` handles two things:

  - A list of fragments (remember this!).
  - back stack of fragment transactions.
- To *add*, *remove*, *attach*, *detach* or *replace*
  fragments in the fragment list you use `Fragment Transactions`.
- When you ask the `FragmentManager` for a fragment using the container
  view id (`findFragmentById`), if the fragment is already in the list,
  the `FragmentManager` will return it. Then you can use it.

> **When Activity initially appears**

Since the app just started, you only have one instance of each fragment. One of `ParentFragment` and one of `ParentFragmentChild`. So far so good.

> **Screen rotation #1**

At this point, the Activity's `FragmentManager` and the ParentFragment's `ChildFragmentManager`save its list of fragments. Then, you can see how both fragments are completely destroyed.

When the Activity is recreated, the new `FragmentManager`s retrieve the list and 
recreate the listed fragments to make everything as it was before the orientation change. Note that are not the same instances, these are new fragments recreated by Android (that's why you can't have a Fragment without the empty constructor, Android needs it to recreate the fragments).

Now, this is the code inside your `ParentFragment`:

```
getChildFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction()
             .add(getId(), new ParentFragmentChild(), ParentFragmentChild.class.getName())
             .commit();
```

You are not trying to find out if `ChildFragmentManager` already has a `ParentFragmentChild` in its list (which already has). That's the reason you can see two fragments being created, the first one is being recreated by the `ChildFragmentManager`, the second is created by the previous code.

> **Screen rotation #2**

There were two `ParentChildFragment` in the ChildFragmentManager's list before the second orientation change, they were recreated and one more is created by the code.

It's better to use the fragments the `FragmentManager` recreates instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Are you saying that fragment managers keep a static list of fragments ? And why does not ParentFragment survive then ?